# Windows 10 folders with dot before names have no names

Tags: windows

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, and a lot of my folders that have a dot before the names now have no names, but exist and function, just blank names. How do you correct this? Most of the folders are in my C:\Users\username folder. I have 26 folders with dots before names in my C:\Users\username parent folder, but only 3 show names. If you go to the properties for each folder you can actually find the name, but it doesn't show in File Explorer. Thanks in advance for any replies.

Edit: When I go to Properties, it will list the file type as (for example, .android) "Folder (.android)" instead of just "Folder", as with other folders. So it's the folder type that is the problem I think.

Comment: I don't have WIndows 10 so can't know for certain, but this sounds suspicously like some "hide file extensions" setting has been set. Check your folder view settings and see if there's anything that looks relevant.

Comment: I have the parent folder set to show extensions and show hidden files already.

Comment: Is it possible to recreate the issue by executing the command `mkdir \\?\C:\Users\username\.examplefolder\´ in cmd.exe? (the `\\?\´ bit is important, using this prefix you can create folders with ANY name)

Comment: I don't think that will work, since the folder already exists, just doesn't show up in File Explorer. I opened the properties for one of the folders and tried to assign the correct name, and it told me the folder already exists.

Comment: If I open a command prompt at the parent folder and do "dir" the folders list correctly there.

Comment: When I go to Properties, it will list the file type as (for example, .android) "Folder (.android)" instead of just "Folder", as with other folders. So it's the folder type that is the problem I think.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it. I opened an elevated command prompt and entered "assoc .android= " (space after the "=") and all the folders showed up in File Explorer. I thought I was going to have to enter the command for each non-showing folder.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what the normal assoc value is for a normal folder ? My Win10 is installing at the moment. I'm going to poke around a bit to see if I can find some logic to this.

Comment: This works, but Windows 10 reverts back after a reboot. Hoping for a permanent solution to this...

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the most obvious and simple solution actually works on windows 10:

Open regedit.exe and goto:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`

add a new DWORD named `ShowFolderExt` and set it's value to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Windows File Explorer has a long history of lying to you.
It doesn't show you what is going on. 
It only shows you what it thinks you should know.
Which is fine for the average user that only has a vague idea what a file or a folder actually is, but this dumbing it down is quite irritating to powerusers and sys-admins that try to troubleshoot things.

And it seems that the Windows 10 version is again slightly worse than the previous versions.
The folders are still there: Explorer just doesn't show them, because Explorer is of the opinion that folders shouldn't have extensions.
(This is a notion that goes back all the way to MS-DOS: In the old FAT filesystems folders could technically NOT have an extension at all.
Modern filesystems are a lot more flexible, but Windows still has some leftover thinking from those days. If you don't believe me: Make folder that ends in a single period. Then try to remove it.)

The only thing you can do is to use an alternative (not made by Microsoft) file-manager utility that shows you reality.
And those alternatives are usually a lot more capable than Explorer anyway.

Personally: I haven't used Explorer for anything serious since WIndows 3.1. I always use an alternative file-manager.

Comment: I fixed it. I opened an elevated command prompt and entered "assoc .android= " (space after the "=") and all the folders showed up in File Explorer. I thought I was going to have to enter the command for each non-showing folder.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this issue after an Upgrade to Windows 10. As part of the post-upgrade activities, I had changed some standard apps (Settings -> System -> Default Apps). Somehow this caused that in the explorer the dot portion of a folder name was not displayed anymore. Clicking the Reset button next to "Reset to the Microsoft recommended defaults" (in Settings -> System -> Default Apps) solved the problem.

[image: Settings -> System -> Default Apps]

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that works more than once in [this StackOverflow answer](https://superuser.com/a/1435785).

The fix is an official tool from Microsoft:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17590/automatically-diagnose-and-repair-windows-file-and-folder-problems

> Note: The tool requires a reboot for the fix to be visible (even though it doesn't prompt you to reboot). I am not sure what option is supposed to fix this problem, so I selected them all.

Unfortunately, Windows 10 still tends to revert back to this state, but unlike the `"assoc .android= "` fix suggested by te7, this solution can be applied more than once. That solution works only the first time it is applied, but when Windows 10 reverts back it cannot be applied again.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, file extensions are not displayed by default in file explorer.

This should do : Click right on Windows icon > Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > File Explorer Options > View Tab > Uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types"

Comment: "I have the parent folder set to show extensions and show hidden files already. – te7 Aug 13 at 8:05" - Why do you suggest the author enable something they already enabled?