# Windows 10 directories ending with "dot something" hides the "dot something"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-management

I have some folders that are organized by the websites I got the files from so they have folder names such as "Website.net" but ever since a few updates ago (must be at least a year) Windows 10 is now hiding the ".net" part in Explorer. So now the folder name is just "Website" when it should be "Website.net". However, the actual folder path is in fact "Website.net" in the address bar, it just doesn't show that way in File Explorer window. Is there a registry setting I can change to make Explorer show the full folder name again? It's really annoying.

Just to clarify, this is not the filename extensions that are missing/hidden. This is the folder names or directories. Thanks.

Using Windows 10 latest updates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I enable .docx, .xlsx etc. at the end of file names?](https://superuser.com/questions/1269427/how-can-i-enable-docx-xlsx-etc-at-the-end-of-file-names)

Comment: Can you clarify it is *folder* names with the problem and not *file* names? Have you tried adjusting your view settings to show known file extensions?

Comment: @Appleoddity Yes, this issue is regarding folder names. I have edited the question.

Comment: Just now found these posts at SU [Windows Explorer cuts off folder names after dot (.) - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/112577/windows-explorer-cuts-off-folder-names-after-dot) & [Windows 10 Explorer cuts off folder name after last period character - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1083173/windows-10-explorer-cuts-off-folder-name-after-last-period-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution on a Microsoft thread titled *Truncated Folder Names ("Extension" Missing)*

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/truncated-folder-names-extension-missing/596fb09b-c41d-42e8-9d14-95a02352d554

A user named Lee Diggins had this exact issue and fixed it using a Windows repair tool titled *Automatically diagnose and repair Windows file and folder problems* which can be found here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17590/automatically-diagnose-and-repair-windows-file-and-folder-problems

This repair tool fixed the problem for me.

When using the repair tool, this exact issue is not listed, but –as Lee Diggins also mentioned in the thread– just check the box for each option to fix all file and folder problems. I did this and after a restart, all my directories are back to normal.

This fix should work for Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10.

Thanks to those who pointed out I was incorrectly referring to "folder names" as "filenames" because this alone helped me research the problem better (and thus discover that Microsoft thread).

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. Did you happen to review the results to see what exactly the tool fixed? I’m very curious as to what actually causes this. If you have a log file it would be good to see relevant info.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, but eventually Windows 10 reverts back to the original state. Fortunately, unlike other solutions I tried this one seems to work after it reverts back.